# How to get the time difference for each array which is a value to dictionary key?

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

I'm reading some data from a database which returned as a dictionary already. I create a new dictionary from the data where the keys are different dates of the year dates and the values are arrays for all the `timestamps('2019-01-01 14:03:02')` associated with the date. I need to find the difference between the timestamps in the arrays for each key in the dictionary.

I have looked at various exercises on stack overflow and online bu to to avail.

```py
import datetime
time1 = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 5, 00, 00, 1)
time2 = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 5, 2, 32, 55)
time3 = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 5, 17, 50, 35)
time4 = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 5, 23, 59, 59)

time5 = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 6, 00, 00, 3)
time6 = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 6, 2, 20, 21)
time7 = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 6, 19, 33, 11)
time8 = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 6, 23, 59, 57)

array = [time1, time2, time3, time4]
array2 = [time5, time6, time7, time8]

dic = {"A": array, "B": array2}
count = 0
sumation = []
total = 0

for k, j in dic.items():
    for i in range(0, len(j) - 1):
        d = j[i + 1] - j[i]
        if d <= datetime.timedelta(hours=6, minutes=20):
            print(d)
            total += d.total_seconds()
    print(total, 'total')
```

I would like to get something like the following:

for array: `array[1]-array[0]+array[2]-array[1]`

for array2: `array[1]-array[0]+array[2]-array[1]`

with the above example representing the total for each array

Comment: So what is wrong with your code? For me it works and produces the desired result.

Comment: I meant to say array2[1]- array2[0]+ array2[2]-array2[1]

Comment: Then please edit you question.